# 360° rotation of image in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i need to know if this effect is possible to achive/mimic in Sencha Touch 2?

http://lukedurrant.com/threesixty/index.htm

Comment: I think it's possible. I'm gonna try to do it and I'll let you know if I succeeded.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Do you think that you by any chance might check it out tonight? I'm kind of on a really tight deadline and im totally stuck here! <3

Comment: Ah ah, I'm gonna try just for fun but I can't promise anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect, but it works great (tried on iPad 2). If anybody wants to improve the dynamic though, be my guest. I suck at it.

[**Projet**](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/Sencha/tree/master/Ext.ux.ThreeSixtyView)

[**Working Example**](http://titouanvanbelle.fr/GitHub/Sencha/Ext.ux.ThreeSixtyView/)

Hope it suits your needs

Comment: Hmm... Seems like i'm getting the first +4 and -4 images right, and the rest gives me a 403 (Forbidden) from the logs in Chrome, and those images doesnt show. It points to 'console.log(e.deltaX, me.deltaX);' in your ThreeSixtyView.js

Comment: It also seems that it resets itself to frame 1, even if you just drag it the first 4 successful pictures!

Comment: Hmm... Checked again, it's only the first 3 images that works, the rest has a GET error 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: Was there the pictures when you downloaded the project ?

Comment: No there wasn't any pictures in the first project i downloaded, had to get my own. But im seeing your live example and that's working fine so i'm gonna try out your new upload as soon as i get home!
But so far it seems that you've done an amazing job!! Thanx alot for helping me out!

Comment: Thanks, just make sure the case is the same when you declare you image names.

Comment: Hmm... Somehow, when i implement your solution in my app, the images have a 75% opacity to them for as long as i hold the mouse down?

Comment: Chrome & Safari having the same effect :/

Comment: Fixed it with opacity settings in CSS!

Comment: hey it seems links are broken can you fix them

Comment: Only the screencast link is broken. but there is a working example